# Edição sugerida aparentemente se perdeu

Tags: bug, status-intencional, edição, filas-de-análise

Em geral, quando estou analisando uma edição sugerida e escolho "Melhorar" ("Improve"), o resultado - se a memória não me falha - é que tanto a minha edição quanto a do editor que fez a contribuição aparecem no histórico. Creio que esse é o comportamento correto - nem que seja para que ambos recebam crédito.

Entretanto, há pouco fui melhorar uma edição, meio que me arrependi e cliquei em "cancelar", depois me arrependi de novo e - no popup - escolhi permanecer na página. Terminei a edição e, no histórico, vi somente a minha edição: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/9985/revisions

Aquele comentário ("O titulo estava muito grande e no corpo da pergunta parecia não ter pergunta...") por exemplo não é meu, é do [usuário que sugeriu a edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5082/silvio-andorinha). E como se pode ver no seu histórico recente, ele não ganhou `+2` de reputação pela edição sugerida - como deveria ter acontecido (não mexi no checkbox "A edição sugerida foi útil", que por padrão fica marcado).

Esse é o comportamento correto? Tenho certeza que me lembro ser diferente. Talvez seja um bug quando se tenta cancelar a edição e se volta atrás...

P.S. Se isso muda alguma coisa, não cheguei lá pela fila de análise, apenas cliquei em "Editar" na própria pergunta quando ela estava mostrando 1 edição pendente - "editar (1)".

Comment: Eu to avaliando o que aconteceu e *acho* que já tenho uma idéia.

Comment: @Gabe A situação foi esclarecida. Creio que cabe um "status-bydesign"... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sugestão foi rejeitada pelo autor da pergunta, então valeu somente a edição que você fez em cima. Isso deve ter ocorrido enquanto você editava. No histórico das análises encontrei o link que esclareceu o caso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6385.

Comment: É, isso explica perfeitamente o que aconteceu. Valeu!