# Por que essa edição foi aprovada?

Tags: bug, status-intencional, filas-de-análise, edições-sugeridas

Vendo o [histórico de edição dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6480), notei que nenhum usuário aprovou a edição. Um usuário escolheu "Editar", depois a ["Comunidade" (robô)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade) aprovou automaticamente. O que aconteceu?

Isso tem alguma relação com [<del>esse provável bug</del> essa situação parecida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099/edicao-sugerida-aparentemente-se-perdeu)? Pois me parece que deve ter acontecido algo muito semelhante ao meu caso, só que dessa vez o usuário que ia editar desistiu. Veja minha interpretação:

- Usuário analisa a edição, e escolhe "Melhorar" (*Improve*);
- Sistema "decide" que a edição vai ser aprovada mesmo, de qualquer jeito;
- Usuário clica em cancelar; aparece um popup de confirmação, e ele confirma que vai cancelar a edição;
- Edição é aprovada apesar de nenhum usuário humano tê-la aprovado.

P.S. Não estou discutindo a edição específica. Eu a rejeitaria como *too minor*, mas agora que foi aprovada não vejo razão pra reverter. O que me intrigou foi a edição ter sido aprovada automaticamente a partir das ações de um único usuário.

P.P.S. Se bem que esse usuário em particular anda fazendo [diversas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6483) [edições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6479) [desse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6481) tipo.

Comment: @brasofilo Ele não está sugerindo, ele está aprovando. Várias dessas edições sem sentido do [Samir Braga](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5918/samir-braga?tab=activity) foram aprovadas por ele.

Comment: Estranho mesmo. Talvez o Lucas Nunes tenha confirmado a edição sem fazer nenhuma alteração em cima da versão do Samir, e o sistema registrou uma única revisão. Isso seria um bug, um _loophole_ que permitiria que muita gente aprovasse ou rejeitasse edições sozinho.

Comment: Particularmente passei a excluir minhas respostas que sofreram tal tipo de edição totalmente desnecessária. Fui informado que, como autor da resposta, poderia rejeitar a edição mas esta opção não está mais disponível porque alguém rapidamente aprovou a edição.

Comment: @Osvaldo Excluir? Por que não simplesmente **reverter**? (inclusive, reverter uma postagem para um estado antigo desfaz todos os votos - positivos ou negativos - obtidos desde aquele momento no tempo) Em tempo: usuários com determinado nível de reputação (atualmente `1000`) podem editar qualquer postagem sem necessidade de aprovação. Entretanto, eles não ganham nada por isso, então é pouco provável que façam edições desnecessárias.

Comment: @mgibsonbr: não me foi apresentada esta opção quando verifiquei qual edição havia sido feita, aliás uma edição bem idiota, não sei porque alguém perde tempo com isso.

Comment: @Osvaldo Clique no histórico de edições (onde está escrito "editada" - e pode ter a foto do último editor, se não foi você mesmo). Você verá uma lista com todas as edições feitas à sua pergunta desde que ela foi criada. Ao lado das edições antigas há um link "reverter". Ao clicá-lo, ela será revertida para aquele ponto no tempo (e, sendo você o autor, a mudança ocorre imediatamente sem precisar de aprovação). Nota: é pra clicar em "reverter" na revisão que você quer **manter**; **todas** as edições **posteriores** serão desfeitas por essa ação.

Comment: @mgibsonbr: Note que na mensagem que é enviada relatando a edição, que remete à edição proposta, não existe esta opção. Creio que seria o lugar mais lógico para constar a opção reverter ou rejeitar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não há bug nenhum. O Lucas Nunes escolheu "Melhorar", como o @mgibsonbr suspeitou, e confirmou a edição sem fazer qualquer alteração. O sistema reconhece isso como um voto implícito de aprovação, e o Comunidade realiza o voto.

A edição foi aprovada automaticamente porque o Lucas Nunes tem mais de 1000 de reputação. Como esse é o limite mínimo para que você possa editar posts dos outros, o sistema entende da mesma maneira (como se ele tivesse feito a edição) e aprova a proposta automaticamente.

Pode parecer uma maneira de burlar o sistema, mas os autores das revisões têm poder de fazer as edições sozinhos, então não faz sentido restringir.

Isso ocorreu diversas vezes até hoje (164, pelos meus cálculos), como vocês podem ver [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14763) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14933).

Comment: Continuo achando meio estranho. Se é assim, qualquer usuário com direito de editar qualquer post poderia também ter o direito de aprovar edições sozinho, o que não é o caso.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não discordo. Não sei bem como foi tomada a decisão de deixar assim, mas acho que o trabalho extra de "melhorar" a edição conta como um apoio implícito maior.

Comment: Se a edição de fato melhorasse alguma coisa... Mas o caso relatado é de clicar em melhorar e salvar sem alterar nada, não? Enfim, concordo que não é grave, e entendo que vai ficar como está, ok.

Comment: Olha eu ali num dos exemplos :D
Acho que tem toda a lógica ficar aprovado, uma vez que eu editei em cima. Se não melhorou nada é estranho sim @bfavaretto.

Comment: @JorgeB. Pois é. Acredito que ninguém discorda que se alguém com mais de 1k de reputação melhorar uma edição, ela deve ser aprovada automaticamente, certo?  Por que deveria ser diferente para uma "melhoria" que altera nada? É o mesmo tipo de apoio tácito de alhuém com autonomia, e confiança, para fazê-lo. Não acho que exista uma resposta certa, nesse caso, então qualquer alternativa tem seu valor.

Comment: Os exemplos que você deu não são do mesmo caso. Repare que tanto quem sugeriu a edição original e quem aprovou/editou por cima aparecem no histórico de edição. No caso descrito na pergunta, somente quem sugeriu aparece no histórico (porque a edição do Lucas não alterou nada). Para mim é claramente uma maneira de burlar o sistema... Não o sistema de edição, mas o sistema de análise.

Comment: @bfavaretto Se minha query está correta, o único outro review que se encaixa no mesmo padrão [é este](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7104). E continuo nao discordando que isso permite contornar as regras de análise, mas ao mesmo tempo não vale a pena combater, considerando o dano que causa. Mesmo no SOen, são só uns 30 casos parecidos com esse.